# Delete a row from Firestore DB using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I delete a row that consists of two values in different arrays in Firestore? (delete fields from the Firestore document)

arrays in the Firestore collection:

1. Food
2. Quantity

**Example of the table:**

[image: table]

**Firebase-related code (delete function):**

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        if (user) {
            const uid = user.uid;
            const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, 'data', uid));
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                await snapshot.update({
                    value: FieldValue.delete(),
                    number: FieldValue.delete(),

                })
            } else {
                console.log('User doc missing');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('User not logged in');
        }
    })
}
```

**table code:**

```
                {/* table */}
            <table className='table table-hover'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Food</th>
                        <th>Quantity (gr)</th>
                        {/* <th>Calories (kcl)</th> */}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {data.map((row, index) => {
                        // calculate calories
                        let calories = Math.ceil(row.quantity * 1.35);
                        return (
                            <>
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                    <td className='font'>{row.value}</td>
                                    <td className='font'>{row.quantity}</td>
                                    {/* <td className='font'>{calories}</td> */}
                                    <p onClick={handleDelete}>X</p>
                                </tr>
                            </>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Fetch data code:**

*NutritionDataInstance is used as a Singletone for using the arrays in separate JS files not to override the fields in the arrays in case of same value was entered instead of using the "arrayUnion" function of Firebase*

```
    useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
        let foodNames = [];
        let quantities = [];
        let foods = [];
        if (user) {
            const uid = user.uid;
            const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, 'data', uid));
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const { value, quantity } = snapshot.data();
                let s = 0;
                for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                    foods.push({ value: value[i], quantity: quantity[i] });
                    foodNames.push(value[i]);
                    quantities.push(quantity[i]);
                    // sum of all calories
                    setSum(s = s + Math.ceil(quantity[i] * 1.35))
                }
                NutritionDataInstance.foodNames = foodNames;
                NutritionDataInstance.quantities = quantities;
                setData(foods);
            } else {
                console.log('User doc missing');
            }
        } else {
            console.log('User not logged in');
            setData([]);
        }
    });
}, [data]);
```

**Firebase Structure:**

[image: Firebase structure]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code that you are using to fetch the document data so we can check if document ID is available? Also, a screenshot of your Firestore structure would help. You just need [`deleteDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) if you have the doc ID to be deleted.

Comment: I edit the question, I hope it will be more understandable.

Comment: Just my two cents, if you store a single array of objects of format `[{ quantity: 240, value: "Rice" }]`, you can then easily use `arrayRemove()` to remove that row only as you know the entire object as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the element at e.g. index = 1 in two different Array fields in a Firestore document you should, **in your case**, do as folows:

1. Read the document in your front-end (i.e. query it from Firestore)
2. Modify the two Arrays in your front-end by removing the values corresponding to the index
3. Write the two fields back to Firestore.

Note that there is an [`arrayRemove()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) method that removes **all instances** of each given element but in your case I don't think you can use it: If you have the same value several times in the `quantity` field, all instances will be removed.

---

Concretely, in your code you need to pass the ID of each document to the table, in such a way that you pass the document ID to your `handleDelete` function.

In addition to

```
const { value, quantity } = snapshot.data();
```

you need to do

```
const docId = snapshot.id;
```

Comment: Hey @Ashka, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?